How can I increment a field if the record already exists?
I have a bash script to dump a csv file to sqlite3:
 cat <<EOF | sqlite3 "$1.db"
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'dump' (
pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
first TEXT,
last TEXT,
seen INTEGER,
created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
UNIQUE(first, last)
);
.mode csv
.separator ";"
.import '$1.tmp' 'dump'
EOF

Which works for basic dump but this dump file is constantly being updated and I need to track the number of times that person is seen. How can I increment the "seen" field if that person is already in the database?

I doubt you can do it with the built-in .import. You should write a script in a programming language that loops through the CSV and performs an upsert.

Import into a temp table and then update the table with whatever you want

a web search on sqlite import csv upsert brings up a few hits that all say the same thing (assuming you're doing this via sqlite3 command line) ... import into a staging table and then insert into main table select from staging table on duplicate key update ... (eg, this)

What is format of input file? The .import command demands that csv file match table schema, meaning you already have pk, seen, and created fields in the .csv file. What is the process of filling/updating these fields in the file?

You have a Bash script that imports a CSV into an SQLite database. The CSV is constantly updated, and you need to increment the seen field for existing records while inserting new ones.
Solution: Efficient UPSERT with SQLite Transactions
To efficiently handle this, we'll use SQLite's INSERT OR REPLACE syntax within a transaction.
cat <<EOF | sqlite3 "$1.db"
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'dump' (
    pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first TEXT,
    last TEXT,
    seen INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
    created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UNIQUE(first, last)
);

.mode csv
.separator ";"

-- Create a temporary table with necessary columns
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_import (
    first TEXT,
    last TEXT
);

-- Import the CSV into the temporary table
.import '$1.tmp' tmp_import;

-- Efficiently insert or update records
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO dump (first, last, seen)
SELECT first, last, seen + 1
FROM tmp_import;

DROP TABLE tmp_import;
COMMIT;
EOF

Explanation:

Begin Transaction: Ensures data consistency, especially for concurrent updates.
Create Table: Creates the dump table if it doesn't exist.
Temporary Table: Creates a temporary table for efficient processing.
Import CSV: Imports the CSV data into the temporary table.
UPSERT: Uses INSERT OR REPLACE to insert new records or update
existing ones, incrementing the seen count.
Drop Temporary Table: Cleans up the temporary table.
Commit Transaction: Commits the changes to the database.


cat is useless here. Straight do sqlite3 "$1.db" <<EOF or sqlite3 "$1.db" <<'SQL' so your here-doc content does not expand shell and is made clear it is SQL syntax.

Script steps.
Step 1. Create temp table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp (…);

Step 2. Create dump table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dump (…);

Step 3. Open a transaction.
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

Step 4. Clear the table:
DELETE FROM temp;

Step 5. Import data into temp table.
Step 6. Merge Data with Upsert:
INSERT INTO dump (…)
SELECT … FROM temp
ON CONFLICT(first, last) DO UPDATE SET
seen = seen + 1
…

Step 7. Commit the changes.
COMMIT;


Based on Md Mahfuz RP's answer with fixed and verified working implementation.
#!/usr/bin/env sh

sqlite3 "$1.db" <<SQL
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'dump' (
    pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first TEXT,
    last TEXT,
    seen INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UNIQUE(first, last)
);

.mode csv
.separator ";"

-- Create a temporary table in memory with necessary columns
PRAGMA temp_store = 2; -- 2 means use in-memory
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_import;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_import (
    first TEXT,
    last TEXT
);

-- Import the CSV into the temporary table
.import '$1.csv' tmp_import

-- Efficiently insert or update records as a single transaction
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Imports new lines from tmp_import if they don't exist in dump
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO dump (first, last)
SELECT first, last
FROM tmp_import;

-- Increment the seen of dump's lines that are in tmp_import
UPDATE dump
SET seen = seen + 1
FROM (
  SELECT first, last FROM tmp_import
) AS t
WHERE t.first = dump.first AND t.last = dump.last;

COMMIT;

-- Dispose of the in-memory tmp_import table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_import;
SQL

